# How to Compare Variables in the Azure Library-Variable Group

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-devops, console-application

I have Variable Groups set for my Test-Demo-Main environments and I have so many variables in it. so before going for each deployment I need to compare each with each environment. Now I am  checking the feasibility to automate this process with a console application.
Could you please share your idea/thoughts on how can I get all the variables from each environment and compare with other env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the SDK to do these operations;

libs:

- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi
- Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient

example to get variables from Group:

```
    Uri _uri = new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/{your org}/");

    VssBasicCredential loginCred = new VssBasicCredential("user", "PAT");

    VssConnection vssConnection = new VssConnection(_uri, loginCred);

    await vssConnection.ConnectAsync();

    var taskagent = vssConnection.GetClient<TaskAgentHttpClient>();

    var var_env_1 = (await c.GetVariableGroupAsync("projectname", 1)).Variables;
    var var_env_2 = (await c.GetVariableGroupAsync("projectname", 2)).Variables;
    var var_env_3 = (await c.GetVariableGroupAsync("projectname", 3)).Variables;

   // 1,2,3 = idgroup, YOU CAN GET THE URL (variableGroupId) WHEN ACCESSING THE GROUP IN AZURE DEVOPS

    // LOGIC TO COMPARE
```

refs:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/tree/main/ClientLibrary/Samples

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops#samples

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?view=azure-devops